# ¿Cómo establecer un formato plano a un documento cargado en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, mvc, entity-framework

Estoy realizando una carga de datos desde un archivo plano, estos mismos tienen un formato así.

> id | fecha   |   hora
>
> 14    2022-06-13 07:30:26
>
> 13    2022-06-13 07:30:29
>
> 3 2022-06-13 07:31:03
>
> 28    2022-06-13 07:34:54
>
> 14    2022-06-13 16:33:15
>
> 13    2022-06-13 17:00:08

Lo estoy cargando en **listas**, pero esto lo carga de manera **lineal**, el problema es realizar un formato, la manera en que se necesita es que evalué si en la fecha se encuentran **2** inserciones, así crear una nueva lista con este formato:

> id    fecha   hora entrada  hora salida
>
> 14    2022-06-13 07:30:26     16:33:15
>
> 13    2022-06-13 07:30:29     17:00:08

He realizado esto, pero no me funciona:

```
     //linea es el documento cargado
     //caracter son los separadores para dividir por columnas el documento
     string[] arreglo;
     string[] aux;
     Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
     aux = linea.TrimStart().Split(caracter);
     arreglo = linea.TrimStart().Split(caracter);

     List<string> lista = new List<string>();
     List<string> listax;
     listax = new List<string>();

     listax.Insert(0, arreglo[0]);
     listax.Insert(1, aux[1]);
     listax.Insert(2, aux[2]);
     listax.Insert(3, aux[3]);
     listax.Insert(4, aux[2]);
     lista.Clear();

            
     foreach (string item in lista)
     {
          aux = lista.ToArray();
     }

    tabla.Rows.Add(aux);
```

Comment: ¿Qué criterio usas para unirlas? ¿Que tengan el mismo id? Por cierto, quizá te [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse) te sea útil.

Comment: Por lo que veo inicializas "lista", esta nunca se llena es una lista vacía, y luego la limpias, y luego quieres iterar en ella. Creo que ahí está tú 1er problema, que la lista al parecer, siempre está vacía.
Si pudieras poner el código completo daría una mejor compresión.

Comment: Si, mira mi idea es mediante el id y la fecha, validar la cantidad de registros, entonces si valida que ya existe un registro en una fecha eso significaría que el id ya registró la hora de entrada, entonces,  la idea es rellenar la "lista" con los datos 

Listax[0] "id"
Listax[1] "Fecha"
Listax[2] "Hora entrada"
Listax[3] "Hora Salida"

Pero este Listax[3] sea el segundo registro de la misma fecha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas he hecho una versión que parece funcionar el output es por consola pero lo puedes adaptar a tu gusto.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
       {   
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader("text.txt");

        stream.ReadLine();//evito el header
        string linea = "";
        List<Valores> lineas= new List<Valores>();
        while ((linea=stream.ReadLine())!=null)//cargo datos
        {
            if(linea!="" && linea!=" ")
            lineas.Add(new Valores(linea));
        }
        
        List<string> ids= lineas.Select(item => item.id).Distinct<string>().ToList();//cogemos las id unicas
        //calculos
        Console.WriteLine("id | fecha | hora entrada | hora salida");
      
        foreach (string valores in ids)
        {

            List<Valores> valores1 = lineas.Where(item => item.id == valores).ToList();
            if(valores1.Count==1)//en caso de que no haya registrado salida
            {
                Console.WriteLine(valores + " " + valores1[0].fecha + " " + valores1[0].hora + " ");
            }
            else if(TimeSpan.Parse(valores1[0].hora)>= TimeSpan.Parse(valores1[1].hora))//comparamos las horas para saber caul es la d'entrada y salida
            {

                Console.WriteLine(valores+" " + valores1[0].fecha+" " + valores1[1].hora +" " + valores1[0].hora);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(valores + " " + valores1[0].fecha + " " + valores1[0].hora + " " + valores1[1].hora);
            }
                    
        }
           
        Console.ReadLine();//paro la ejecucion evitable



    }
   public class Valores
    {
        public Valores(string text)
        {
          string []  s = text.Split();
           
            id = s[0];
            fecha= s[1];
            hora = s[2];
        }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string fecha { get; set; }
        public string hora { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return id +" "+fecha+" "+hora;
        }
    }
```

Resultado:

id | fecha | hora entrada | hora salida

14 2022-06-13 07:30:26 16:33:15

13 2022-06-13 07:30:29 17:00:08

3 2022-06-13 07:31:03

28 2022-06-13 07:34:54